# Search for 'keyword', display row values and move between selected source and target spread sheet in html using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

**My progress:** I have list of spreadsheets consisting of many sheets. In each Spreadsheet, first sheet is a database; and the Column A data use as 'keyword' for searching.

I have created Spreadsheet with following data to use for populate Source and Target Spreadsheet.

- Column A - dropdown displaying name - data Source
- Column C - dropdown displaying name - data Target
- Column B - data Source - Spreradsheet ID
- Column D - data Target - Spreradsheet ID
- Column E - Source Spreradsheet has multiple sheet. sheet name which data available
- Column F - Target Spreradsheet has multiple sheet. sheet name which data to be copied

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SourceSp_name A | Source_SpreadS A ID | TargetSp_name A | Target_SpreadS A ID | Source Sheet_name A | Target_Sheet_name A |
| SourceSp_name B | Source_SpreadS B ID | TargetSp_name B | Target_SpreadS B ID | Source Sheet_name A | Target_Sheet_name B |

---

html shows as below.

[image]

After choose both drop-downs, enter keyword and search. Then matching data row in the Source Spreadsheet is displaying in html with "move" button at the end. [up to this working fine]

**Issue:**

```
After clicking move button at the end of data row in html, data not moving
```

[image: keyword matching data row with move button]

ATTEMPTED SOLUTION/Try: My current script (see it below!) seems ok but not moving. As self learner, tried catch-up error using console.log. Debugger showing all "DataRow: undefined" and "TargetSheetName: undefined" . Question is: Cannot figure out next step to take.

Here is my current script for move data:
at H.html;

```
function moveData(dataRow) {
    console.log('moveData function started');
    var sourceSpreadsheetId = dataRow[1];
    var sourceDataSheetName = dataRow[4];
    var targetSpreadsheetId = dataRow[3];
    var targetDataSheetName = dataRow[5]; // Use the target data sheet name from the dataRow

    google.script.run.moveData(dataRow, targetDataSheetName); // Call the moveData function in the server-side code
    alert('Data moved successfully.');
  }
```

at code.gs

```
function moveData(dataRow, targetSheetName) {
  console.log('moveData function started');
  console.log('DataRow:', dataRow);
  console.log('TargetSheetName:', targetSheetName);

  try {
    var sourceSpreadsheetId = dataRow[1];
    var sourceDataSheetName = dataRow[4];
    var targetSpreadsheetId = dataRow[3];
    var targetDataSheetName = dataRow[5]; // Use the passed targetSheetName parameter

    var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
    var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
    var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceDataSheetName);
    var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetDataSheetName);

    targetSheet.appendRow(dataRow);

    // You can adjust this based on your data structure
    sourceSheet.deleteRow(1);
      console.log('Data moved successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in moveData:', error);
  }
}
```

Here's link to webapp [display and move data web app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxvuKN53FL-OHvK00H280jV0pAFa8IUljCzKFTwsxiqVymSxNovQL3MfJc7I029Q4Uo/exec)

I expected to enter [source database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pEWv0h3-cecZMEtXg9RK4Q7-zSkh9MEjDrQHP8BRy-w/edit?usp=sharing)  "column A value" as a "keyword" in above webapp. For example, If I enter 998965301330 value as "keyword", relevant data row displayed but move not working.

Here's link for code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcstj94k/)

Here's link to spreadsheets [1. Spreadsheet list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzGmPnvapcku8ZPtM6sJLcQq4eDOmi8ZGXOhQNG_svA/edit?usp=sharing) , [2. source database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pEWv0h3-cecZMEtXg9RK4Q7-zSkh9MEjDrQHP8BRy-w/edit?usp=sharing)  , [3. target database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YZrOiI9dCeIoqNBnOgEMv36hqOIfDynhN9Z0sqvGt50/edit?usp=sharing)

I understood, movedata function is to be modified to catch rowIndex (keyword matching row) in source and move it to target. Please help me to use rowIndex for moveData function

Comment: [Spreadsheet.createTextFinder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: @Cooper Here I trying to move complete row of data from one spreadsheet to another via html. Source and Target spreadsheet choose from dropdowns...

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have 3 questions. 1. I cannot understand the values of "Column E" and "Column F" in your top table. Can I ask you about the details of them? 2. In your script, the values of `var sourceSpreadsheetId = dataRow[1];`, `var sourceDataSheetName = dataRow[4];`, `var targetSpreadsheetId = dataRow[3];`, and `var targetDataSheetName = dataRow[5];` are valid values? 3. About `sourceSheet.deleteRow(1);`, do you always want to delete 1st row?

Comment: @Tanaike 1. Column E = Source Tab (**database**). Column F= Target Tab (**target**).  2. 'Column B' =`dataRow[1]` , 'Column D' =`dataRow[3]`. is not necessary if I get method to catch-up matching **rowIndex** in source sheet. Now I understand that after displaying correct data row, no need to repeat searching of keyword. please help me to apply rowIndex.  3. `sourceSheet.deleteRow(1);` actually what i want is delete matching **rowIndex** data row after copying correctly on target sheet. ("database" to "target"). Not that first row but matching **rowIndex**. Help me to modify movedata function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. About `1. Column E = Source Tab (database). Column F= Target Tab (target).`, what are `Source Tab (database)` and `Target Tab (target)`? For example, in your showing table, "E3" and "F3" are the same with "C3" and "D3", respectively?  But, it seems that "E2" and "F2" are different from "C2" and "D2", respectively. From this situation, I'm confusing your showing table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand `2. 'Column B' =dataRow[1] , 'Column D' =dataRow[3]. is not necessary if I get method to catch-up matching rowIndex in source sheet. Now I understand that after displaying correct data row, no need to repeat searching of keyword. please help me to apply rowIndex.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: About `3. sourceSheet.deleteRow(1); actually what i want is delete matching rowIndex data row after copying correctly on target sheet. ("database" to "target"). Not that first row but matching rowIndex. Help me to modify movedata function.`, in your question, if you want to copy a row from the source sheet to the target sheet and want to delete the copied row under multiple source Spreadsheets and target Spreadsheets are existing, I think that not only the copied row number but also the selected source and target Spreadsheets are required to be used. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry about my bad explanation skills. I will explain again. Each spreadsheet has multiple sheets. "database" is one of sheet in source spreadsheet. searchkey data available in column A of "database" sheet. I want to copy matching data to Target spreadsheet, sheet name "target". Check I given spreadsheet links

Comment: @Tanaike Column A to Column E is one separate spreadsheet use only for populate drop down. Column A = name display on dropdown for source spreadsheet , Column B = relevant Spreadsheet ID, Column C = name display on dropdown for target spreadsheet. Column D = same as column B, but for Target spreadsheet. Column E an F are sheet names (because source and target spreadsheet are multiple sheets,so i ned to name them)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I cannot still understand columns C, D, E and F in your top table. About `I will explain again.`, you say `I want to copy matching data to Target spreadsheet, sheet name "target".`. In your actual question, you want to copy a row of source sheet to target sheet instead of move the row. Is my understanding correct? And, about `Column E an F are sheet names`, in your showing table, it seems that "D3" and "F3" are the same value. But, you say `Column D - data Target - Spreradsheet ID`. In your actual situation, you are using Spreadsheet ID as a sheet name?

Comment: I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. I'm confused about understanding the actual expected result of your question. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: @TanaikeThank you for the help, sorry for my bad communication skill. 1. I want to move data (MOVE = Copy row to target spreadsheet and delete source spreadsheet. )  2.  Please note that "Spreadsheet ID" , "Spreadsheet name" and "Sheet name" are three different things. E and F are sheet names. that's correct. B and D are ID's.  Please see I clearly explained A to F above that  TABLE.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misudnerstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the source and target Spreadsheet IDs and sheet names from "H" Spreadsheet.
- You want to move a specific row from the source sheet to the target sheet by selecting the row on the HTML table.

#### Modification points:

- Your showing script is incomplete. But, when I saw the actual script of your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the value of `dataRow` is the row value of the source sheet. In this case, all values of `var sourceSpreadsheetId = dataRow[1];`, `var sourceDataSheetName = dataRow[4];`, `var targetSpreadsheetId = dataRow[3];`, `var targetDataSheetName = dataRow[5];` are invalid values. From this situation, in your script, it is required to prepare valid values for moving the row from the source sheet to the target sheet between Google Apps Script side and HTML side.
- Also, in your situation, it is required to use the row number for deleting the row. But, in your showing script, the 1st row is always deleted by `sourceSheet.deleteRow(1);`.

When these points are reflected in your actual script in your provided Spreadsheet, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet() {
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID of "H" spreadsheet.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName("dropdown");
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(([srcSSName, srcSSId, dstSSName, dstSSId, srcSheetName, dstSheetName]) => ({ srcSSName, srcSSId, dstSSName, dstSSId, srcSheetName, dstSheetName }));
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  html.data = JSON.stringify(values);
  return html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function getSrcValues({ sourceSheet: { srcSSId, srcSheetName }, keyword }) {
  var sheetH = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSSId).getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  var range = sheetH.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var obj = values.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == keyword) {
      o.rowIndexes.push(i);
      o.data.push(r);
    }
    return o;
  }, { rowIndexes: [], data: [] });
  if (obj.rowIndexes.length > 0) {
    var confirmationMessage = "Matching data found. Do you want to move it to the target sheet?";
    return { success: true, message: confirmationMessage, data: obj.data, rowIndexes: obj.rowIndexes };
  }
  return { success: true, message: "No matching data found.", data: [] };
}

function moveData({ dataRow, rowIndex, sourceSheet: { srcSSId, srcSheetName }, targetSheet: { dstSSId, dstSheetName } }) {
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSSId).getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  var dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSSId).getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  srcSheet.deleteRow(rowIndex + 1);
  dstSheet.appendRow(dataRow);
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    th, td {
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Search and Move Data</h1>
  <div>
    <label for="sourceSheet">Source Sheet:</label>
    <select id="sourceSheet">
      <option disabled selected>Select Source Sheet</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="targetSheet">Target Sheet:</label>
    <select id="targetSheet">
      <option disabled selected>Select Target Sheet</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="keyword">Keyword:</label>
    <input type="text" id="keyword" onkeydown="if (event.key === 'Enter') searchAndMove()">
    <button onclick="searchAndMove()">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div id="searchResults"></div>

  <script>
  updateSourceSheets();

  function updateSourceSheets() {
    var data = <?!= data ?>;
    var sourceSheetDropdown = document.getElementById('sourceSheet');
    sourceSheetDropdown.innerHTML = '';
    data.forEach(({srcSSName, srcSSId, srcSheetName}) => {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = JSON.stringify({srcSSId, srcSheetName});
      option.text = srcSSName;
      sourceSheetDropdown.appendChild(option);
    });

    var targetSheetDropdown = document.getElementById('targetSheet');
    targetSheetDropdown.innerHTML = '';
    data.forEach(({dstSSName, dstSSId, dstSheetName}) => {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = JSON.stringify({dstSSId, dstSheetName});
      option.text = dstSSName;
      targetSheetDropdown.appendChild(option);
    });
  }

  function searchAndMove() {
    var [sourceSheet, targetSheet] = ['sourceSheet', 'targetSheet'].map(e => JSON.parse(document.getElementById(e).value));
    var keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
    google.script.run.withUserObject({sourceSheet, targetSheet}).withSuccessHandler(displaySearchResults).getSrcValues({sourceSheet, keyword});
  }

  function displaySearchResults(data, {sourceSheet, targetSheet}) {
    var searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');
    searchResults.innerHTML = '';

    if (data.success) {
      searchResults.innerHTML = data.message + '<br>';

      if (data.data.length > 0) {
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.border = '1';
        var headerRow = table.insertRow(0);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.data[0].length; i++) {
          var headerCell = document.createElement('th');
          headerCell.innerHTML = 'Column ' + (i + 1);
          headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
        }

        data.data.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
          var dataRow = table.insertRow(rowIndex + 1);
          row.forEach(function (cell, cellIndex) {
            var cellElement = document.createElement('td');
            cellElement.innerHTML = cell;
            dataRow.appendChild(cellElement);
          });

          var moveButton = document.createElement('button');
          moveButton.innerHTML = 'Move';
          moveButton.onclick = function (e) {
            if (confirm('Do you want to move this data?')) {
              console.log('Move button clicked');
              moveData(row, data.rowIndexes[rowIndex], {sourceSheet, targetSheet}, e);
            }
          };

          var buttonCell = document.createElement('td');
          buttonCell.appendChild(moveButton);
          dataRow.appendChild(buttonCell);
        });

        searchResults.appendChild(table);
      }
    } else {
      searchResults.innerHTML = data.message;
    }
  }

  function moveData(dataRow, rowIndex, {sourceSheet, targetSheet}, e) {
    console.log('moveData function started');
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => {
      e.target.closest('tr').remove();
      alert('Data moved successfully.');
    }).moveData({dataRow, rowIndex, sourceSheet, targetSheet});
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Testing:

When you open the Web Apps using your browser, you can see that the dropdown list has already been loaded. When you input "Keyword" and click "Search" button, an HTML table is shown when the search value is found. When you click "Move" button, this row is moved from the source sheet to the target sheet. And, the move row is removed from the HTML table.

If you want to keep the moved row in the HTML table, please remove `e.target.closest('tr').remove();`.

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this. So, please test my modified script using your provided Spreadsheet.
- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".